# Sort two different vectors (that each have "active" bool) with one function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector

I create the base class which has the ACTIVE BOOL

```
class BaseTest{
public:
    bool active = false;

    BaseTest(){
    // make most true
        if ( getRand(0, 5) != 2){
            active = true;
        }
    }
};
```

create two different child classes

```
class ChildTest_1: public BaseTest{

    string child1 = "Is child 1";

public:

    ChildTest_1(){

    }
};

class ChildTest_2: public BaseTest{

    string child2 = "Is NOT child 1";

public:

    ChildTest_2(){

    }

};
```

I want to be able to pass either child (or any vector with "ACTIVE") to this function and it will return the first inactive. I have a program that runs a lot of vectors of many objects and usually have a class that manages each object vector. It is becoming a pain and waste of repeated code to write this loop in every mgmt class. I want one that I can pass any vector that has objects with an active var.

I don't need sorting right now, but that was the closest term to what I need.

What I need is a function I can pass a vector to and it will return the first inactive object;

It would be even better if they did not need to share a base class as long
as each object in the vector has its own ACTIVE bool, but I can also make a simple base class that all would derive from.

```
int firstInactive(vector<BaseTest> & test ){

    for ( int cnt = 0 ; cnt < test.size() ; cnt++ ){

        if (!test[cnt].active){

            cout << cnt << " Is inactive " <<endl;

            // add actual sorting here if I need;

            return cnt;
         }

    }

}



int main(int, char const**){



    vector< ChildTest_1 > allTest1;

    vector< ChildTest_2 > allTest2;


    allTest1.resize(10);

    allTest2.resize(10);



    cout << "First inactive in alltest1 is " << firstInactive(allTest1) <<endl;

    cout << "First inactive in alltest2 is " << firstInactive(allTest2) <<endl;

// as expected it says no known matching function call.    

    return 0 ;

}
```

I've searched and experimented for a few days now. I've read everything I could on polymorphism and templates, but cannot find an example that helps me.

Answer (score 5):

You may use template (No base class required):

```
template <typename T>
auto firstInactive(const std::vector<T>& v)
// -> typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator // for c++11
{
    return std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const T& e) { return !e.active; });
}
```

and call it:

```
std::vector<ChildTest_1> allTest1(10);
std::vector<ChildTest_2> allTest2(10);

auto it1 = firstInactive(allTest1);
auto it2 = firstInactive(allTest2);

if (it1 != allTest1.end()) {
    std::cout << "First inactive in alltest1 is "
              << std::distance(allTest1.cbegin(), it1) << std::endl;
}
if (it2 != allTest2.end()) {
    std::cout << "First inactive in alltest2 is "
              << std::distance(allTest2.cbegin(), it2) << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Xy1uXQ)

Comment: I got an error with the Template, but changed my dialect to c++14 because I couldn't figure out where the "-> std::vector<T>::const_iterator " which I think I need anyway because I got an error with the std::distance in the if statment that resolves an int from the it1, saying "no matching function call" because the it1 is apparently not a const_iterator

Comment: @CoryWissler Actually, `it1` (and `it2`) are probably `const_iterator`s, as in Jarod's code his function `firstInactive` takes in a const (reference) vector. Try changing `allTest1.begin()` (and `allTest2.begin()`) to `allTest1.cbegin()` (and `allTest2.cbegin()`). Anyway, I'm guessing that's what that problem is.

Comment: @CoryWissler: c++11 is good enough, just the iterator type has to be fixed: `cbegin` instead of `begin` to force `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
T getFirstInactive(const std::vector<T>& v){
    for (const auto& i : v){
        if (!i.active) return i;
    }
    return T();
}

struct Foo{
    bool active;
    int x;
    Foo() : active(true),x(0) {};
};

int main(){
    auto v = std::vector<Foo>(10);
    v[4].active = false;
    v[4].x = 3;
    std::cout << getFirstActive(v).x << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
3
```

However, you probably dont want a copy, but a reference to the element. In that case it might be better to make the template return an iterator. (Also the template has to return something in case there is no inactive element, which is much nicer with iterators).

Answer (score 0):

I experimented and came up with this solution based on both of your answers:

```
template <typename T>
int getFirstInactive(const std::vector<T> & obj){
    int itr = 0;

    for (const auto& i : obj){

        if (!i.active){
            return itr;
        }

        itr++;

    }

    return itr;

}
```

this returns the index number of the first inactive object, then all I need is to see if that index number is the same as the size, in which cash I push_back a new object. problem solved, thanks!